# NullPointerException in com.sun.tools.jxc.SchemaGenTask

Tags: java, ant, jaxb

Given this ant script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="projectname" default="generate-schema" basedir=".">

    <taskdef name="schemagen" classname="com.sun.tools.jxc.SchemaGenTask">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="../BuildJars/lib" includes="*.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <target name="generate-schema">
        <schemagen srcdir="src/gb/informaticasystems/messages" destdir="schema">
            <schema namespace="http://www.informatica-systems.co.uk/aquarius/messages/1.0" file="messages-1.0.xsd" />
        </schemagen>
    </target>

</project>
```

I am getting this error:

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\davidcollie\workspace\aquarius-feature\AquariusServerLibrary\schemagen.xml
generate-schema:
[schemagen] Generating schema from 4 source files
[schemagen] Problem encountered during annotation processing; 
[schemagen] see stacktrace below for more information.
[schemagen] java.lang.NullPointerException
[schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.jxc.model.nav.APTNavigator$2.onDeclaredType(APTNavigator.java:428)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.jxc.model.nav.APTNavigator$2.onClassType(APTNavigator.java:402)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.jxc.model.nav.APTNavigator$2.onClassType(APTNavigator.java:456)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.istack.tools.APTTypeVisitor.apply(APTTypeVisitor.java:27)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.jxc.model.nav.APTNavigator.getBaseClass(APTNavigator.java:109)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.jxc.model.nav.APTNavigator.getBaseClass(APTNavigator.java:85)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.getIndividualType(PropertyInfoImpl.java:190)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.<init>(PropertyInfoImpl.java:132)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.MapPropertyInfoImpl.<init>(MapPropertyInfoImpl.java:67)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.createMapProperty(ClassInfoImpl.java:917)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.addProperty(ClassInfoImpl.java:874)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.findGetterSetterProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:993)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:303)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:243)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:209)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:315)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:330)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.j2s.JavaCompilerImpl.bind(JavaCompilerImpl.java:90)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.jxc.apt.SchemaGenerator$1.process(SchemaGenerator.java:115)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessors$CompositeAnnotationProcessor.process(AnnotationProcessors.java:60)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.apt.comp.Apt.main(Apt.java:454)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.apt.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:258)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Main.java:1102)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Main.java:964)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.processing(Main.java:95)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Main.java:85)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Main.java:67)
[schemagen]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[schemagen]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[schemagen]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[schemagen]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.jxc.AptBasedTask$InternalAptAdapter.execute(AptBasedTask.java:97)
[schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.jxc.AptBasedTask.compile(AptBasedTask.java:144)
[schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:820)
[schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
[schemagen]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[schemagen]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[schemagen]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[schemagen]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
[schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
[schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
[schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
[schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1298)
[schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[schemagen]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
[schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1181)
[schemagen]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:423)
[schemagen]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:137)

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\davidcollie\workspace\aquarius-feature\AquariusServerLibrary\schemagen.xml:11: schema generation failed

Total time: 1 second
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue because my srcdir was set to the package folder which contained the java files.

Changing this to the top level source folder was better, but then schemagen wanted to make a schema for all .java files on my source path (only 20% were actually jaxb classes).

My final ant call looks like:

```
<property name="event.package" value="my/organisation/events"/>
<schemagen srcdir="${src.main.java.dir}" 
    destdir="META-INF/event-schema" 
    classpathref="build.classpath">
    <include name="${event.package}/Event1.java"/>
    <include name="${event.package}/Event2.java"/>
</schemagen>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<schemagen>` task needs to include a classpath, probably the equivalent to what's in the `<javac>` task that, no doubt, lives somewhere else in your Ant script. I'm also questioning the value of the `srcdir` attribute. It should point to the top of your source tree, and not within any packages. It looks to me like "gb.informaticasystems.messages" might be a package in your project. If so, you should change the attribute to `srcdir="src"`. So, it should look something like this (you need to supply the classpath):

```
<target name="generate-schema">
    <schemagen srcdir="src" destdir="schema">
        <schema namespace="http://www.informatica-systems.co.uk/aquarius/messages/1.0" file="messages-1.0.xsd" />
        <classpath>
           <!-- Classpath definition goes here -->
        </classpath>
    </schemagen>
</target>
```

Comment: Not quite it but it did get me looking at the Java Bug Parade which pointed me at the version of the JDK. I switched from running the ant script from 1.6 to 1.5 which then caused *proper* stack traces to be thrown and from there I fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Maybe you could submit the answer yourself, just in case someone else comes to Stack Overflow with a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

I switched from running the ant script from 1.6 to 1.5 which then caused proper stack traces to be thrown and from there I fixed the problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your problem/solution was?  All my classes on the classpath are compiled to 1.6...

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is very likely that some classes are missing which are used in the classes from which you want to create a schema.
In my case I had to include some missing classes which haven't been in my first set of matched wildcards. I have used Maven and I had to switch from the jaxb2-maven-plugin version 1.6 to 1.5 which shows some errors when the verbose is set to true. Later I switched back to the most recent version.

```
                 <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <id>rest-webservice-schemagen</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>schemagen</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*DTO.java</include>
                            <include>**/*Type.java</include>
                            <include>**/*Status.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```